# Spring security in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to implement security to my spring boot application and have followed this http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/30/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/ . after implementing this i am getting an error as following :

```
Expression parsing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire  method: public void 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setContent
NegotationStrategy(org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy);
```

This is my Application.class

```
public class Application  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}

@Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
private String databaseDriverClassName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String datasourceUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String databaseUsername;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String databasePassword;

@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(databaseDriverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
    ds.setUsername(databaseUsername);
    ds.setPassword(databasePassword);

    return ds;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}


@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
{
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return slr;
}

public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor()
{
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");

    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

I have two model classes named Gizmo.java  and GizmoChild.java
This is my Controller class

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    Gizmo gizmo = new Gizmo();
    gizmo.getChildren().add(new GizmoChild());
    model.addAttribute("gizmo", gizmo);
    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping("/save")
public String save(Gizmo gizmo) {
    System.out.println(gizmo.getField1());
    System.out.println(gizmo.getField2());
    for(GizmoChild child : gizmo.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(child.getChildField1());
        System.out.println(child.getChildField2());
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

}

This is my SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();


        userDetailsService.setDataSource(datasource);

        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);


        if(!userDetailsService.userExists("user")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
            User userDetails = new User("user", encoder.encode("password"), authorities);

            userDetailsService.createUser(userDetails);
        }
    }


}
```

I am not getting any compilation errors but while running error is coming.
Please help me to resolve this issue .This is the only place i am stuck , if there are any documentation regarding spring boot security please tell me.

Comment: Remove the datasource bean, spring boot provides that for you. Also remove the `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` spring boot does that for you. Replace it with a `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`. Your configuration is also weird as you are configuring and adding a `JdbcUserDetailsManager` and next override it with `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource()` as that effectively replaces it again. So you are messing around quite a bit.

Comment: So you mean  to remove the Datasource  bean in Application.class and remove @EnnableWebSecurity in securityconnfiguration.class ??

Comment: yes, as that is already provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: my issue is  solved by adding h2database  dependency to my pom.xml

Comment: I've taken a look at the tutorial you follow, well I wouldn't follow it. It tries to explain things but fails at correctly doing so and it doesn't acknowledge the things that Spring Boot already provides (like the datasource and already enabled security).

Comment: Can you please tell me on what should i follow ??

Comment: Well you can follow it but I would suggest that you read up on Spring Boot and especially the auto configuration features and what it already gives you. You would also want to read the sections in the reference guide on the features you want (security) and what that already does and how you can override it. Although your error seems not really related to this (maybe that is a dependency or other configuration issue) but if you learn something you should learn it well.